# Oracle Apex version 4.2.0.00.27 upgrade to 19.1 - Old applications has no CSS, new ones are fine

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex

We upgraded our Oracle Apex version 4.2.0.00.27 to 19.1, but the old applications now appears jumbled like the CSS is missing. New applications are however fine and styled nicely in the 19.1 look. How is this possible? Are the old Apex 4 themes no longer there or do we have to perform a missing upgrade step?

We are using the Apache Tomcat web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to file system and copy all image and css files. Old  apps will be fine then.

Comment: From where to where? Shouldn't they be there already if it's an upgrade?

Comment: No they are not there look at all  your old pages . use Browser developer tools f12  see those css links in html. ( jumbled like the CSS is missing ),. upgrade  replace css files and images folder with new images. But  it does not retain old pictures or any css. It is  delete and copy operation rather than replace files. I hope you have old back up files on web server before you did in place upgrade. Put css file back from backup folder on iis or your webserver.